# how to link model with types in mongoose with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` with `typescript` in `node.js`

my model definition -> album.model.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

interface Album {
  title: string,
  price: Number
}

const schema = new Schema<Album>({
 title: { type: String, required: true },
 price: Schema.Types.Decimal128
});

const albums = mongoose.model("albums", schema);

export default albums;
```

Album API -> album.ts

```
import express from "express";
import albums from "../../models/albums";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/albums", async (req, res) => {
 
const _albums = await albums.find({}); //line #1

const albums= _albums.map((item) => { //line #2
               return {
                 title: item.get("title").ToUpperCase()
                      }})};

export default router;
```

However, I am not getting the static type checking of Typescript like when I mouse hover, I see that at line #1 `_albums` is of type `any` & the same is for `item` at line #2

While what I am looking for `_albums` to be array of `Album` & `item` to an instance of `Album` & so that I can access the properties by `.` like

```
_albums.map((item) => { //line #2
                   return {
                     title: item.title.ToUppercase()
                          }})};
```

Links I checked.

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose (Deprecated)

How can I get this static type checking/casting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do this?

```
const albums = mongoose.model("albums", schema<Album>);
```

If so you could make a third type such as

```
interface AlbumDocument implements Album {
  title: string,
  price: Number,
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
  id: string
}
```

And use that like this to solve the issue

```
const albums = mongoose.model("albums", schema<AlbumDocument>);
```